# Is it ok to update mysql cell and searching by this cell at the same time

Tags: mysql

Is it ok to update mysql cell and searching by this cell at the same time
To make it a bit clearer, I'd like to show code:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `cell`='foo' WHERE `cell`='bar'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly fine. When the Update happens, it is like a frozen point in time so you don't have to worry about circular loops or missing your intended target.

1) MySQL finds the rows/columns specified in the WHERE clause.
2) MySQL does the UPDATE.

This would only cause an issue if you tried to run this multiple times in succession with the same criteria trying to get the same data (which has already been changed).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the order in which this instruction is executed:

1. Find the row(s) in `table` where the value of column `cell` is `'bar'`
2. Set the value of column `cell` to `'foo'` in every row found in the previous step

There's nothing that prevents you from doing it